# Why the length of the weight vector is likely to grow?

Tags: neural-networks, regularization

In the book Michael Nielsen's Neural Networks and Deep Learning, in chapter 3 he writes: "Heuristically, if the cost function is unregularized, then the length of the weight vector is likely to grow, all other things being equal". Can you explain why the length of the weight vector is likely to grow?

Comment: It may be helpful to see it expressed in eqaution form. The length of the weight vector is given by $\Vert w \Vert$ (Euclidean norm). Using regularization, we want to minimize a cost function $C$ that is given by: $$ C = C_1 +\lambda \Vert w \Vert^2$$ where $C_1$ represents the unregularized cost function. In that equation we can see that big values of $\Vert w \Vert$ are penalized as they would make $C$ big $\Rightarrow$ with regularization, lower values of $\Vert w \Vert$ are achieved

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, all other things being equal, increasing the number of connections (increasing the weight vector) allowed to be searched will never lead to a worse model on trained data, as in the aggregate of the new neural net simply setting the added connections to weights $0$ will at least be able to perform as well as the old model.

And there is always some probability of some combination of non-zero weights performing better. Hence trained models when given the chance will seek to add these combinations.

This is the core of the overfitting problem however and is why regularisation is used regularly in practice.

Comment: the length of the weight vector is likely to grow means norm of weight is increasing. Is that right?

Comment: Um I haven't read the book you're referring to but I'm assuming he means vectors as the actual row vector, not the Euclidean sense. So the number of elements is what is actually increasing.

Comment: This is the rest of the paragraph "Over time this can lead to the weight
vector being very large indeed. This can cause the weight vector to
get stuck pointing in more or less the same direction, since changes
due to gradient descent only make tiny changes to the direction,
when the length is long. I believe this phenomenon is making it
hard for our learning algorithm to properly explore the weight
space, and consequently harder to find good minima of the cost
function."

Comment: Okay sure he's just interpreting the vector in Euclidean space then in a geometrical interpretation. They represent the same thing though hence the argument still applies. As you go from a specific n-dimensional vector to an n+1 dimensional vector, the Euclidian-norm can never decrease and always increases for new non zero elements. He's actually making another point though about the length of a vector and its relationship to the inertia of its direction when new elements are added, but im not sure thats the same question as your original.

Comment: You said 'the Euclidian-norm can never decrease and always increases for new non zero elements'. Why is that? Is it based on the weight update formula using gradient descent or something else?

Comment: No its a geometrical argument. Intuitively adding dimensions shouldn't reduce the length. But algebraically the euclidian norm is the square root of the inner product. Adding elements is always positively increasing.

Comment: Oh, I see. One more thing. Why we add dimension to the weight vector? I thought regularization is used to reduce the magnitude of weights and without regularization magnitude of weights increases, leads to overfitting, there is no relation to add dimension to weight vector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116598/discussion-between-duy-phan-and-dale-c).